# iphone ui control to manage multiple things

Tags: iphone, configuration, authentication, uicontrol

how is called  this ui control to manage multiple things like in the contacts or for classic user/passwords?
like this for example:

[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/f3a70d97dc2579457db8c28d95c5694a.png](http://grab.by/grabs/f3a70d97dc2579457db8c28d95c5694a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with style : UITableViewStyleGrouped.

If there is only a UITableView in your view controller, you can directly use a [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You might be interested in the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) (highly recommended).

The one in the screenshot customizes its cells by adding UISwitch in them.